# Where did Ravi get the tainted Utopium?

Tags: vertigo-comics, izombie-2015

A major plot point during the first season of *iZombie* is the creation of a cure for zombie-ism. This is done by recreating the source of the zombie infection using tainted Utopium. It is rather important that the tainted Utopium is in limited supply.

However, I can't seem to find out how Ravi got his hands on this limited supply of tainted Utopium. Was it ever mentioned on screen how he got this, or did it just mysteriously show up without an explanation?

Comment: Uhh... Its been a while, bu wasn't he using the tainted energy drink? In the second season he is indeed looking for the tainted drug, since the energy drink has been recalled.

Comment: @Yasskier I think that in both seasons, it's about combining the tainted Utopium with the energy drink.

Comment: I think you should hide the Spoilers from such a new TV show...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 its hardly a spoiler since Ravi's willing to find the cure for zombie disease is declared about 20 minutes in first episode and the fact that Liv is a zombie is well, in the title.

Comment: Hmm, I would assume that as a pathologist he would have access to the leftover drug from the Party Massacre,